# Remove last HYPHEN from url string segment on form submit

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

On my codeigniter project When I click on my submit button I have a script where changes the url to something like below it adds the search input to url.

`http://localhost/project-ask/questions/tagged/how-to-use-/`

> **Question** How can I remove the last  HYPHEN `-` in segment 3 this `/how-to-use-/` would be segment 3 when I click on submit so it would look like some thing `/how-to-use/`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#form-search").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        str = $('#input-search').val();
        url = "<?php echo base_url('questions/tagged/');?>" + str.replace(/\s/g, "-");
        window.location = url  + '/';
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I think is called em dash `-`

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

Your `$('#input-search').val()` holds `how-to-use-`

The trailing slash `/` is added on `window.location`.

So:
This removes the last character if it is a "dash".
Preventing the removal if it isn't... Maybe can happen.
;)

```
$(function() {
    $("#form-search").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        str = $('#input-search').val();
        if( str.charAt(str.length-1) == "-" ){
          str = str.substr(0, str.length-1)
        }
        url = "<?php echo base_url('questions/tagged/');?>" + str;
        window.location = url  + '/';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for every ones answers I had to do a couple changes from [@Louys Patrice Bessette](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2159528/louys-patrice-bessette) answer

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#form-search").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        str = $('#input-search').val();

        // adds hyphens for string 
        var newstr = str.replace(/\s/g, "-");

        // Removes last hyphen from @Louys Patrice Bessette answer
        if( newstr.charAt(newstr.length-1) == "-" ){
          newstr = newstr.substr(0, newstr.length-1)
        }

        url = "<?php echo base_url('questions/tagged/');?>" + newstr;
        window.location = url  + '/';
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Glad my answer helped. Yes... I answered quite fast. But it got you on tracks ;) Please accept your own answer to mark this as resolved.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I have to wait two days to accept it own answer thanks again

Answer (score 1):

How about this solution. Hope it helps!

```js
var str = "/how-to-use-/";
var myString  = str.slice(0, str.length - 2) + str.slice(str.length - 1);
console.log(myString);
```

Comment: If using `.slice()`, why wouldn't you say `str.slice(0, -2) + str.slice(-1)`?